# Как перезаписать только измененные файлы, Unzip Linux

Tags: linux

Как сделать, чтобы при распаковке архива, он заменял **только измененные файлы**. Сейчас строка выглядит так `unzip -o #{to} -d #{path}`
Префикс `-o` делает перезапись всех файлов без вопроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в программу `unzip`, насколько мне известно, не вложена требуемая функциональность.

если места для распаковки архива в другой каталог достаточно, то можно воспользоваться (после распаковки) программой *rsync*.

иллюстрирующий пример:

```
$ mkdir src
$ touch src/file1
$ zip -r 1.zip src
  adding: src/ (stored 0%)
  adding: src/file1 (stored 0%)
```

теперь распакуем во временный каталог:

```
$ unzip 1.zip -d temp
Archive:  1.zip
   creating: temp/src/
 extracting: temp/src/file1
```

и запустим *rsync* с опцией `-n` (*dry run*), чтобы не копировать, а только посмотреть, что будет копироваться. как видим, *rsync* не будет копировать ничего:

```
$ rsync -n -av temp/src/ src/
sending incremental file list

sent 64 bytes  received 12 bytes  152.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

а если файл в исходном каталоге изменён, то *rsync* его перезапишет:

```
$ touch src/file1
$ rsync -n -av temp/src/ src/
sending incremental file list
file1

sent 67 bytes  received 15 bytes  164.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

**обновление**

для полной синхронизации, возможно, имеет смысл воспользоваться ещё и опцией `--delete` — с нею *rsync* удалит те файлы, которых нет в *источнике* (каталоге `temp/src`). продолжая вышеприведённый пример:

```
$ touch src/file2
$ rsync -n -av --delete temp/src/ src/
sending incremental file list
deleting file2
./
file1

sent 62 bytes  received 27 bytes  178.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

появившаяся в выводе строка `./` означает, что у каталога `src` будет восстановлено время его последнего изменения (время изменилось на текущее после выполнения команды `touch src/file2`).

Comment: Мне изначально надо скопировать содержимое из одной папки в другую, заменяя измененные файлы. просто я сначала архивировал папку, а потом копировал. можно сразу тогда пользоваться утилитой rsync, минуя архиватор

Comment: тогда вам имеет смысл ещё обратить внимание на опцию `--delete`: с нею *rsync* удалит файлы, которых нет в *источнике*.

Comment: спасибо, помогли )

Comment: а что дает опция `-av` ? В хелпе не понял

Comment: 1. `-a (--archive)` — режим «архивации», просто сокращение для целого набора опций (`-r -l -p -t -g -o -D` или, сокращенно `-rlptgoD`), тут и рекурсивный обход каталогов, и многое другое. 2. `-v (--verbose)` — повышенная «разговорчивость».